# How to loop through loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I am trying to loop the numbers 1 to 1000 in such a way that I have all possible pairs, e.g., 1 and 1, 1 and 2, 1 and 3, ..., but also 2 and 1, 2 and 2, 2 and 3, et cetera, and so on.

In this case I have a condition (amicable_pair) that returns true if two numbers are an amicable pair. I want to check all numbers from 1 to n against each other and add all amicable pairs to a total `total`. The first value will be added to the total if it is part of an amicable pair (not the second value of the pair, since we'll find that later in the loop). To do this I wrote the following "Java-like" code:

```
def add_amicable_pairs(n)
  amicable_values = []
  for i in 1..n
    for j in 1..n
      if (amicable_pair?(i,j)) 
        amicable_values.push(i)
        puts "added #{i} from amicable pair #{i}, #{j}"
      end
    end
  end
  return amicable_values.inject(:+)
end
```

Two issues with this: (1) it is *really* slow. (2) In Ruby you should not use for-loops.

This is why I am wondering how this can be accomplished in a faster and more Ruby-like way. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why we should not prefer using `for-loops` in ruby? I just wanted to know

Comment: As with a for loops, use `1.up_to(n) do |i|` or `(1..n).each do |i|` instead. How fast given loop is depends heavily on amicable_pair implementation.

Comment: Another user stated that [it is very rare to use for-loop in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22723021/how-to-make-terniary-statement-work-in-for-loop#22723167). And so far others or myself have always found a way to do it without a for-loop which is more elegant.

Comment: @Log1c, you can use for loops in Ruby if you want. But actually, internally they are converted to calls to `each`, so just using the `each` method makes it clearer what is actually happening.

Comment: Ah I see, interesting. And `1.up_to(n)` is indeed nicer!

Comment: @user2609980 more than ruby looping functions/methods last answer by hammer at this link will fasten code execution.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114256/how-to-solve-project-euler-21-faster

Comment: @user2609980 see code here at https://ideone.com/21zVX0 it is really fast.

Comment: One important difference between using a for-loop and an enumerator is that the for-loop variable (e.g., i) is in scope after the loop's 'end' statement, whereas enumerators use variables whose scope is confined to their associated block.  Generally, the latter is preferable, but the former could be useful if, for example, you wanted to know the value of a for-loop variable if you were to break from the loop.  I'm not advocating the use of for-loops, however.  I never use them, as I always seem to find a better alternative.

Comment: @AlokAnand My code is still running (it outputted 6368, 6232 pair last). Why is your code so much faster?

Comment: @user2609980 sorry for late reply as it was night here. Your code in add_amicable_pairs method uses either 2 level iteration or using array product method which in itself uses iteration to combine numbers within individual array, my code in same method uses single iteration. Your code in amicable_pair? method calls d(n) 2 times where my code in same method calls d(n) only one time, in amicable_pair?(a, b) a is b for previous method call so I am keeping it in a hash. Your method d(n) uses n/2 my code there uses sqrt(n)..... That is why my code is faster.

Comment: @user2609980 otherwise to find sum of amicable numbers is same.

Comment: @AlokAnand Hmm is it possible to only go up to sqrt(n)? I know that it is possible for checking if it is prime, but now I think you should go up to n/2 since we are not looking for primes but proper divisors. And thanks a lot for your explanation. You have a `repo {}` object which dodges the double iteration which I find bit difficult to understand for now. I will take a look at it. Interesting that the amicable_pair? method is a bottleneck as well. Without the sleeping of my computer the code has been running for about 8 hours and last output is still from pair 6368, 6232. :-) Thanks!

Comment: @user2609980 you can use n/2 also, it won't decrease performance much, repo{} is keeping value of b in key->value pair and previous method call's b is current method call's a parameter. Use puts repo, it will print hash and it will become easy for you to see how it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has `O(n^2)` runtime, so if `n` gets moderately large then it will naturally be slow. Brute-force algorithms are *always* slow if the search space is large. To avoid this, is there some way you can directly find the "amicable pairs" rather than looping through all possible combinations and checking one by one?

As far as how to write the loops in a more elegant way, I would probably rewrite your code as:

```
(1..n).to_a.product((1..n).to_a).select { |a,b| amicable_pair?(a,b) }.reduce(0, &:+)
```

Comment: Alex thanks a lot! Full code is [here](https://github.com/erooijak/projecteuler/blob/master/21.rb). It has been running for the last half hour now and it is at 1200/10000.

Comment: @user2609980 it's a Cartesian/Cross product of the range 1 to `n`.

Comment: Apparently [there are formulas for generating amicable pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amicable_numbers#Rules_for_generation), but they won't generate all pairs, so unless you want to dive down the mathematical rabbit hole and try to invent a new, fast algorithm that generates all amicable numbers, I don't think you'll improve on the `O(n^2)` algorithm by more than a constant factor, especially for large `n`.

Comment: [This answer to "How to solve project euler #21 faster?"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8193233/456814) may be of interest. Also, [Project Euler 21: Sum of Amicable Pairs Under 10000](http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-21-sum-of-amicable-pairs/).

Comment: Thanks @Cupcake. Interesting! :) (Code is still running...)

Comment: @Cupcake That Cartesion/Cross one is faster than a double loop? Or is it internally still a double loop?

Comment: @user2609980 the number of pairs between a set of `n` numbers joined with itself is equal to `n^2`, so generating all the pairs necessarily takes on the order of `O(n^2)` steps, no matter what algorithm you use, unless I'm missing some clever combinatorial trick. In fact, it's not just `O(n^2)`, but rather `Theta(n^2)`. Using the `product` method just uses less code than using for-loops (again, unless I'm missing a combinatorial shortcut).

Answer (score 2):

```
(1..1000).to_a.repeated_permutation(2).select{|pair| amicable_pair?(*pair)}
.map(&:first).inject(:+)
```

Comment: Two things I do not understand: (1) `*pair`, where does it come from? Is pair the output from `.permutation(2)`? Then what is the `*`? (2) What does `&:first` mean? Thanks!

Comment: `permutation` returns a pair `[x, y]`. `pair` receives it, and `*pair` decomposes it as separate arguments. `map{|x| x.first}` takes the first argument of each pair.

Comment: thanks a lot. It is much slower than the original method though!

Comment: @user2609980 I highly recommend that you pick up a copy of [Programming Ruby: The Pragmatic Programmers' Guide](http://pragprog.com/book/ruby/programming-ruby). It's also known as the "Pickaxe" book in the Ruby community, and is considered to be the de facto standard guide to the Ruby language in English. Also, the [Ruby Programming wiki book](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming) is a free resource that you can use.

Comment: @Cupcake OP's code is slow because of mathematical logic he is using and to some extent because of code too.

Comment: @sawa is `permutation` a correct choice here? It won't generate a pair like `(1,1)`, I think you'll need a cross-product for that.

Comment: @Cupcake Woops, you are right. I need `repeated_permutation`.